# Progress bar simulation of the boot process

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog

I have progress bar:

```
  <div id="progress-modal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="bar" :style="{ width: progress2 + '%' }">
                            <span>{{ progress2 }}%</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And I want to show it, gradually fill it up to 100, close and continue to perform the function.

```
        $("#progress-modal").modal('show')
        this.progress2=0;
       setInterval(function () {
           this.progress2+=5
           if (this.progress2>100){
               this.progress2=0;
            //   return;
           }
       },10000)
        $("#progress-modal").modal('hide')
```

But the modal window disappears immediately.
Open->add task
http://task.ru.xsph.ru/

UPDATE:

```
    $("#progress-modal").modal('show')
                this.progress2=0;
  while (this.progress2<=100){
                    setInterval(function () {
                        this.progress2+=10;
                    },0.1)
                }
                $("#progress-modal").modal('hide')
```

Comment: Right now your code reads like this: "Ok computer, show the modal. Now set progress to 0. Now here's a function to call every ten seconds. Now hide the modal." All of that happens almost instantly and it doesn't care what you've provided as that function passed to `setInterval`. I'm thinking you just want to put the call to hide the modal in the `if (this.progress2>100)` check.

Comment: I I want to show a modal window, fill the progress bar to 100 (this.progress2), then hide the modal window. And that it would be gradually for the human eye.

Comment: Right, so you shouldn't hide the modal until the progress is at 100

Comment: I do that. See updates. But you can see the work on the link. The application just hangs.

Comment: your updated code isn't doing what you think. The while loop is basically telling the computer to make `setInterval` calls until the progress is at 100. So a huge amount of `setInterval` calls are going to get made before the function being passed to `setInterval` is even executed once. Your first example seemed like it would work, except you need to put the call to hide the modal inside the `if (this.progress2>100)` check.